# How can I insert an Ajax result into an input value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, class

How can I *insert* an Ajax result into an input value?

#### HTML/PHP

```php
<select id="getcategory" name='categoryname' ><option>SELECT---</option>
    <?php
        $getcat = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY categoryname ASC");
    while($rec = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getcat)) { ?>

        <option><?php echo $rec['categoryname']; ?></option><?php } ?>

</select><br>
<input class='categoryprefix' type='text' name='subcatprefix' />
```

Ajax

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#getcategory").change(function(){
            var cprefix = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getCategory.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {categoryname: cprefix},
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".categoryprefix").append(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note:
File *getCategory.php* is good

Comment: Add `success = function(data) { document.getElementsByClassName('categoryprefix')[0].value = data; }`

Comment: Please use the code formatting tools to make your code readable

Comment: `$(".categoryprefix").val(data);` - inputs get `val()`

Comment: This one worked ! "$(".categoryprefix").val(data); - inputs get val() – Kinglish " Thank you Kinglish

Comment: What do you mean by *"File getCategory.php is good"*?